# How to perform an update in Cassandra across tables?

Tags: join, nosql, cassandra, updatemodel

How do you deal with a schema change in Cassandra ? 
Say i have

```
table users (u_uuid, first name)
```

and

```
table videos(v_uuid, name)
```

as well as

```
table users_videos (uuid, u_uuid, first name, v_uuid, name)
```

. After 6 months i decide to change the schema with new data that i have about my users' 'Last name'. How do i update all of my tables (users and users_videos) to add the last name data, after i 've done an ALTER? How to load the data in each and everyone of the tables with consistency ?
In other words how do you deal with massive updates given that you cannot join the data ?

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CQL, you can use [BATCH statement](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#batchStmt) to execute multiple updates / inserts atomically:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  UPDATE...
  UPDATE...
  UPDATE...
  ...
APPLY BATCH
```

In case you are trying to manipulate a large amount of rows once, you may want to look at [Cassandra bulk loader](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/bulkloader).

Comment: So `Batch` can be used to insert/update different table in the same `Batch` ?